# Windows 7:ATI has monitors backwards, Windows has them right

Tags: windows, display, amd-radeon

When I go into my ATI Radeon HD5700 Series Properties, and choose Color Management, then Identify monitors, it shows monitor 1 on right, and 2 on left. When I go to Windows 7 display properties, Windows has it correct (1 on left, 2 on right). Assumingly by some sort of virtual Windows identification.

This is kind of annoying since applications will open on ATI's monitor 1 (right). I want left to be monitor 1 default.

How can I fix ATI so that monitor 1 is on left, and 2 on right?

When I open ATI CCC, I don't see much outlining this.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which number is which.  Just set whichever you want to be the primary and new applications should open there by default.  (Old applications will probably remember where they were).

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter, but if you really care, just switch the cables, then arrange the screens in Windows so that Windows and ATI agree.

Answer (score 0):

Under ATI's CCC, go under **detect displays** and click on the #2 monitor.  There should be a menu item or a right click menu to make that monitor the primary.